# Elasticsearch - score for collection's items

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem, how to get score (`_score`) for items of collection of found document (embedded documents).

E.g. I'm looking for a product with specific part. So I want to get information which part matched best.

To be precise: I don't want to limit the number of inner documents (parts of product) in the result set. I just need to know which part matched best.

My mapping:

```
"products": {
  "properties": {
    "Id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "RelationshipId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Parts": {
      "properties": {
        "PartName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "CompanyId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "IsPrimary": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My query result:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "localhost",
            "_type": "products",
            "_id": "9AEEA518-D4F1-E611-8274-8CDCD44D0F98",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "Id": "9AEEA518-D4F1-E611-8274-8CDCD44D0F98",
               "Name": "Test1",
               "RelationshipId": "B51AA2C8-D3F1-E611-8274-8CDCD44D0F98",
               "Parts": [
                  {
                     "PartName": "abc 1",
                     "CompanyId": "9EEEA518-D4F1-E611-8274-8CDCD44D0F98",
                     "IsPrimary": "1"
                  },
                  {
                     "PartName": "wer 2",
                     "CompanyId": "BAAF7E32-D4F1-E611-8274-8CDCD44D0F98",
                     "IsPrimary": "0"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your query as well

Comment: @user3775217 right now it was just "match_all"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the only solution is to used `nested` collection. Without it all documents inside the collections are flattened into a set of "variables" and you cannot know from which document the hit came from.

To use nested collections with `score` for each element:

1) Convert inner collection into `nested` with following entry: `"type": "nested"`

2) Adjust queries to use `nested` operator.

3) To query (what uses nested collection) apply `"inner_hits" : {}` entry.

4) With query result the `score` will be "hidden" inside path: `hits.hits.inner_hits.COLLECTION_NAME.hits`. Parse it and join by `Id` with the main result (not every collection item may have been hit). Use `score` value for each inner document to sort the source collection in the main result set.

That's it. Details are in the documentation.